# Bug with ArrayAdapter and Search function?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

When I search for a value in my list of names, it returns the corresponding value. But when I delete this value, my ListView does not return all the names on the list again, they disappear. How to solve this? Any idea?

Code of `TabelaActivity.java`:

```
package com.akzonobel.malote.tabela;

import com.akzonobel.malote.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

/*
 * Very basic Activity, the only things it does
 * are get the ListView reference from our layout.
 * Create an Adapter, set the Adapter to the ListView
 * and handle the onItemClick events for when the user
 * clicks on a row.
 */
public class TabelaActivity extends Activity {
    EditText inputSearch;
    CSVAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabela);

        //Lookup our ListView
        ListView mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mList);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        //Create Adapter. The second parameter is required by ArrayAdapter
        //which our Adapter extends. In this example though it is unused,
        //so we'll pass it a "dummy" value of -1.
        mAdapter = new CSVAdapter(this, -1);

        //attach our Adapter to the ListView. This will populate all of the rows.
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        /*
         * This listener will get a callback whenever the user clicks on a row. 
         * The pos parameter will tell us which row got clicked.
         * 
         * For now we'll just show a Toast with the state capital for the state that was clicked.
         */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                TabelaActivity.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

Code of `CSVAdapter.java`:

```
package com.akzonobel.malote.tabela;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.TextView;


/*
 * Very basic Custom Adapter that takes state name,capital pairs out of a csv
 * file from the assets and uses those values to build a List of State objects.
 * Overrides the default getView() method to return a TextView with the state name.
 * 
 * ArrayAdapter - a type of Adapter that works a lot like ArrayList.
 */
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") public class CSVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State>{
    private List<State> filteredModelItemsArray;
    private Filter filter;
    Context ctx;

    //We must accept the textViewResourceId parameter, but it will be unused
    //for the purposes of this example.
    public CSVAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

        //Store a reference to the Context so we can use it to load a file from Assets.
        this.ctx = context;

        //Load the data.
        loadArrayFromFile();
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
          filter  = new ModelFilter();
        }
        return filter;
      }


    /*
     * getView() is the method responsible for building a View out of a some data that represents
     * one row within the ListView. For this example our row will be a single TextView that
     * gets populated with the state name.
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */

    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
        /*
         * Using convertView is important. The system will pass back Views that have been
         * created but scrolled off of the top (or bottom) of the screen, and thus are no
         * longer being shown on the screen. Since they are unused, we can "recycle" them
         * instead of creating a new View object for every row, which would be wasteful, 
         * and lead to poor performance. The diference may not be noticeable in this
         * small example. But with larger more complex projects it will make a significant
         * improvement by recycling Views rather than creating new ones for each row.
         */
        TextView mView = (TextView)convertView;
        //If convertView was null then we have to create a new TextView.
        //If it was not null then we'll re-use it by setting the appropriate
        //text String to it.
        if(null == mView){ 
            mView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
            mView.setTextSize(19);
            mView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        //Set the state name as the text.
        mView.setText(getItem(pos).getName());

        //We could handle the row clicks from here. But instead
        //we'll use the ListView.OnItemClickListener from inside
        //of MainActivity, which provides some benefits over doing it here.
        return mView;
    }

    /*
     * Helper method that loads the data from the states.csv and builds
     * each csv row into a State object which then gets added to the Adapter.
     */
    private void loadArrayFromFile(){
        try {
            // Get input stream and Buffered Reader for our data file.
            InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("states.csv"); 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;

            //Read each line
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {


                //Create a State object for this row's data.
                State cur = new State();
                cur.setName(line);

                //Add the State object to the ArrayList (in this case we are the ArrayList).
                this.add(cur);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ModelFilter extends Filter
    {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
            {
                ArrayList<State> filteredItems = new ArrayList<State>();

                for(int i = 0, l = getCount(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    State m = getItem(i);
                    if(m.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(m);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<State> allItems = new ArrayList<State>();
                for(int i = 0, l = getCount(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    State m = getItem(i);
                    allItems.add(m);
                }
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = allItems;
                    result.count = allItems.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            filteredModelItemsArray = (ArrayList<State>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for(int i = 0, l = filteredModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(filteredModelItemsArray.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
    }
```

Code of `State.java`:

```
package com.akzonobel.malote.tabela;


/*
 * Basic Data class to hold a state name and the state capital.
 */
public class State {

    private String name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old bug that's never been addressed by Android. It was first reported here, [Issue 9666](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9666), then closed and reopened as Issue [69179](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69179).  I wouldn't hold my breath on it being fixed anytime soon.  If you're curious to read more on the details of why, I wrote a small [blog post](http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/filtering-problems-arrayadapter/) talking about it.

More or less, if you want to filter your data and also add, remove, update, etc portions of it...you'll need to extend BaseAdapter and write your own solution.  Or save yourself some time and take advantage of my frustrations in doing that some many times over and over that I just threw it all into an opensource library. Solves all the filtering bugs and then some: [Advanced-Adapters](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters).